# How can I set-up a Jenkins job to read from an excel file and use this as my build parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for help to create a Jenkins job which reads a value from an excel file and then use this as one of the build parameters for my job.

I have found the following documentation and I have downloaded the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin, but I am unsure where in the job config I can set this up:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readcsv-read-content-from-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace

I am relatively new to Jenkins so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked for a solution already on this page and others but have not been able to find anything that helps me. I have included a screenshot below of how my job is currently parameterised:

[jenkins job screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brh8K.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve question quality. Edit the question to include code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that can be compiled/tested. Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to see what questions you can ask. See: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)